# Trying to manipulate individual elements of a vector in R

Tags: r

My goal is to count the number of times the vector goes from a positive value to a negative value, and vise versa. I would save it under 'changes' for instance. E.g.

```
randomvector <- c(0, 3, 2, -1, -4, -1, 2, 5, 8, 6, 3, 1, -2, -1, 1, 0, 3)
```

In this case, 'changes' would be 4, (2 followed by -1, -1 followed by 2, 1 followed by -2,  -1 followed by 1)

This is what I have so far.

```
Point1 <- c(1:16)
Point2 <- c(2:17)

Number = 0
  if(randomvector[Point1] >0 & randomvector[Point2]) {
      Number = Number + 1
}
Number
```

So essentially, my code is saying: if the first value of randomvector is >0, and the second value of randomvector is <0, add 1 to 'Number'. 'Number' is used as a count to keep track of how many times this occurs. The vectors Point1 and Point 2 start at 1 and 2 and go to 16 and 17 respectively because I want the if statement to move through each successive pairs of numbers in the vector randomvector.

This is what I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (randomvector[Point1] > 0 & randomvector[Point2]) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

> Number
[1] 0
```

I understand the output of 0 as the code doesn't run after it hits the error in the if statement. I also understand the error, that if statements don't work for vectorised objects. I'm not really sure how to attack this, or whether I'm even using the best method. If I'm not, using the completely wrong method feel free to let me know.

Thanks !

Comment: Well, using `if` on a vector is certainly a "wrong way to go". Look at `ifelse` for vector conditional operatuions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be to test when the absolute difference in `sign` of sequential values is 2

```
sum(abs(diff(sign(randomvector))) == 2)
# 4
```

since

```
sign(randomvector)
# [1]  0  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1  0  1
```

and

```
diff(sign(randomvector))
# [1]  1  0 -2  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0 -2  0  2 -1  1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
randomvector <- c(0, 3, 2, -1, -4, -1, 2, 5, 8, 6, 3, 1, -2, -1, 1, 0, 3)
TestVec = randomvector[-1] * randomvector[-length(randomvector)]
which(TestVec <0) +1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be using `rle`. Ignore the `0` numbers and find out number of times a value changes.

```
length(rle(sign(randomvector[randomvector!=0]))$lengths) - 1
#[1] 4
```

Comment: Thankyou! I have other code which counts how many times it goes to zero  (I also want to know that too) so I'll just add the two values together